# How can I convert a string to a double precision in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How can I convert a string to a double precision in PostgreSQL ?

I tried something like :

```
update points set latitude2 = cast(latitude as double) ;
```

where latitude is a string and latitude2 is a double. I just can't get it to work.

Comment: "*can't get it to work*" is not a valid Postgres error message. Please post the complete error (or describe what exactly isn't working)

Comment: Eww this is a *really* bad question for another reason because you're asking about Longitude and Latitude and they shouldn't be stored as a doubles anyway.

Answer (score 55):

`double` is not a postgres data type:

> ```
> select cast('324342' as double);
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  type "double" does not exist
> LINE 1: select cast('324342' as double);
>                                 ^
> ```

but `double precision` is:

> ```
> select cast('132342' as double precision);
> ```
>
> ```
> | float8 |
> | :----- |
> | 132342 |
> ```

So try:

```
update points set latitude2 = cast(latitude as double precision) ;
```

if you prefer, you can use `float` <sup>*</sup> instead, because according [to the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT):

> float with no precision specified is taken to mean double precision

> ```
> select cast('132342' as float);
> ```
>
> ```
> | float8 |
> | :----- |
> | 132342 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8c37b8ec4d82487b05b455dc34aa7fc2)*

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> *or `float(n)` where 25<=n<=53 because that is also [taken to mean double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16889190/533832)*</sub>